# Two redirections instead of one for Lower Case

Tags: redirect, iis

When I add the following rule to the redirection file:

```html
<rule name="To Lowercase" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Images/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="GET" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to WWW">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^foo.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.foo.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

And attempt to open webiste "Foo.com" watching network behaviour I can see that it's first redirected (301) from "https://Foo.com" to "http://foo.com" and then from "http://foo.com" back to "https://foo.com" with status 302.

Is there a way to modify this rule to make just one redirection?

Comment: Do you have other rules in your web.config? Looks like another rule is causing redirect

Comment: yes there is another one - I've added it to the code block above

Comment: So, basically, you have three "rules": lowercase, force www, and force https. Is it correct?

Comment: Hi Victor, yes there is force https at load balancer level as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answers in comments, you can just simply specify the domain name in your rules to avoid multiple redirects. For example:

```
<rule name="To Lowercase" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/Images/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="GET" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.foo.com/{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rule name="Redirect to WWW">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^foo.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.foo.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```